# Mapping within macro without extra parentheses?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

Say I have a macro like this:

```
(define-syntax (choose stx)
  (define data (syntax->datum stx))
  (define args (cadr data))
  (define body (cddr data))
  (define output
    `(apply (case (car ,args)
              ,(map (lambda (choice)
                           `((,(car choice)) ,(cadr choice)))
                         body)
              (else (displayln "error")))
            (cdr ,args)))
  (println output)
  #'(void))
```

If I use this on something like this (there could be more options):

```
(choose args
        ("run" runsomething)
        ("del" delsomethingelse))
```

It transforms it to

```
(apply
 (case (car args)
   ((("run") runsomething)
    (("del") delsomethingelse))
   (else (displayln "error")))
 (cdr args))
```

Which is not valid code, because the map gave it extra parentheses. Instead I want it to give me this:

```
(apply
 (case (car args)
   (("run") runsomething)
   (("del") delsomethingelse)
   (else (displayln "error")))
 (cdr args))
```

How could I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unquote-splicing` (aka `,@`) to get rid of the list surrounding `map`.

Example:

```
(define xs '(a b c))
`(1 2 ,xs  3 4)    ; => '(1 2 (a b c) 3 4)
`(1 2 ,@xs 3 4)    ; => '(1 2 a b c 3 4)
```

However I notice that you use `syntax->datum` on the input `stx`
of the syntax transformer. That removes lexical information, which
could end up causing problems. It recommend using either `syntax-case`
or `syntax-parse`, which use pattern matching to pick out the elements
of the input syntax and templates to generate the output.

```
(define-syntax (choose stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_choose args
              (datum fun-expr)
              ...)
     #'(apply (case (car args)
                [(datum) fun-expr]
                ...)
              (cdr args))]))

(define (run-it . xs) (list 'ran-it  xs))
(define (del-it . xs) (list 'delt-it xs))

(choose (list "run" 1 2 3)
        ("run" run-it)
        ("del" del-it))

Output: '(ran-it (1 2 3))
```

Comment: You say it `syntax->datum` removes lexical information, but isn't that solved by the first parameter (`ctxt`) of `datum->syntax`?

Comment: No. The datum->syntax approach gives the same context (that os the choose form) to everything. The args, and fun-exprs might have a different context.

Comment: Example: If args is produced by one macro and fun-exprs by another, then the contexts are different.

Comment: So it will work fine usually, but not in combination with other macro's?

Comment: If everything inside `(choose ...)` is written "by hand" it ought to work with your `datum->syntax` approach.